# gets an error whenever I try to install lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

Every time I try to `pip install lxml` in my terminal, I get this following messages
with an error that says

```
ollecting lxml
sing cached lxml-3.4.4.tar.gz
nstalling collected packages: lxml
unning setup.py install for lxml
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/pg/bl7db8d57glfhyvf3l5mwb1h0000gn/T/pip-build-ZX2pvH/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/pg/bl7db8d57glfhyvf3l5mwb1h0000gn/T/pip-LwWVjA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
warnings.warn(msg)
Building lxml version 3.4.4.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/html
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron
copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml
copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/src
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/src/lxml
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/pg/bl7db8d57glfhyvf3l5mwb1h0000gn/T/pip-build-ZX2pvH/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/etree.so
building 'lxml.objectify' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/private/var/folders/pg/bl7db8d57glfhyvf3l5mwb1h0000gn/T/pip-build-ZX2pvH/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.objectify.o -w -flat_namespace
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.objectify.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/lxml/objectify.so
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml': Permission denied
```

with an error that says

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/pg/bl7db8d57glfhyvf3l5mwb1h0000gn/T/pip-build-ZX2pvH/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/pg/bl7db8d57glfhyvf3l5mwb1h0000gn/T/pip-LwWVjA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pg/bl7db8d57glfhyvf3l5mwb1h0000gn/T/pip-build-ZX2pvH/lxml
```

And still couldn't figure out the way to install this program properly...any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to run the installation with `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install lxml
```